# How do I get traffic source for each video?

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

TL;DR: Want to get % of views from external traffic source for each video (not for each day)

Long story short, I'm working on a project where I'm trying to understand what factors influence video views on a niche channel I have.

One factor I want to look at is the percent of views from external sources. To track this, I want to measure the traffic source types by each video for ~500 videos.

See example screenshot from the YouTube analytics built in page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnUar.png)

I have been able to get views/title/tag/thumbnail url easily using python, but I have not been able to get the percent of views from external sources from each video.

Is this possible? A link to a working page in the API explorer would be great. I would like to not  have to go through every single one of my 500 videos get this number by hand, although I suppose I could write a macro that does that...

Comment: Did you try with YouTube Analytics?, if so, this option is (or not) acceptable to you? - press [edit] and add what have you tried so far.

Comment: Yea, I've done this. It doesn't allow you to get the data in that type. Like I said I've been able to get views per video but not traffic source per video.